# Simulate Active Directory lastLogonTimestamp attribute update

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Based on the following article i tried to replicate the calculation that is done to decide if the lastLogonTimestamp will be updated or not.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/

```
# Get the users lastLogonTimestamp
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity TestUser -Properties lastLogonTimestamp

# Whatever value 'ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval' is set (14 default)
$TimeSyncInterval = 14

# $TimeSyncInterval - (Random percentage of 5)
$X = $TimeSyncInterval - (5/100*(Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 100))

# CurrentDate - lastLogonTimestamp
$YFileTime = (Get-Date).ToFileTime() - $User.lastLogonTimestamp
$YDays = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($YFileTime)).Day

# Update or not?
if($X -lt $YDays) {
    Write-host "update lastLogonTimestamp" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
elseif($X -gt $YDays) {
    Write-host "do not update lastLogonTimestamp" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

If i wouldn't convert the time difference into 'days' the calculation would be something like `11 - 69352598407` and therefore wouldn't make any sense.

If i now run the above scriptblock through a loop it will never tell me that an update would happen.
There is no chance the property gets updated when lower than 9 days (if you stick to 14 as TimeSyncInterval)

You can manipulate the CurrentDate to simulate the future by adding e.g. 9 days.

```
$YFileTime = ((Get-Date).AddDays(9)).ToFileTime() - $User.lastLogonTimestamp
```

If i now run the script again through the loop it tells me that sometimes an update would happen.

```
1..100 | Foreach-Object {
    # script from above
}
```

I seems right to me what i did up there but maybe there is some further input from some AD legends roaming around here.

Please leave your feedback!

Comment: At first glance, You have misspelled the variable `$YFileTime` in line `$YDays = ([datetime]::FromFileTime(YFileTime)).Day`. (you omitted the `$`). Is that a typo or is this the actual code?

Comment: If you seek a review of or feedback on working code, please post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com - additionally, I'd suggest adding the pupose/motivation behind attempting to replicate this behavior if you want qualifed and useful feedback :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is less about the actual code. I more about improving knowledge about the mechanic involved with the 'lastLogonTimestamp' attribute and supporting this with a script to make it more visible. But thanks for the tip with codereview.stackexchange

Comment: Is there a scenario when knowing this would be valuable?

Comment: @GabrielLuci A couple weeks ago i was asked why the lastLogonTimestamp does not match with the users information about logon to his device. I can for sure explain the bare fact to everyone asking me. But with the script i put together i can simulate and show that it won't or rarely will update based on the parameters given.

Comment: Were they not satisfied with that documentation from Microsoft?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Sometimes visualization helps a lot to better understand a configuration.

Comment: True, but if you haven't been asked for the visualization, then you're likely just wasting your time.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I learned something too in this whole story, so no time was wasted